# Al momento de seleccionar los botones de un videojuego, solo selecciona 1 así se presione el botón que se presione

Tags: javascript

Cuando quiero seleccionar otro botón que no sea el de tierra, lanza un ataque de tierra igual. Ya revisé varias veces la declaración de las variables y me parecen correctas, capaz no estoy viendo algo muy obvio.

También revisé que los arrays tengan valor y con lo poco que llevo aprendido me parece que sí.

```
// Funcion iniciar juego
    const sectionSeleccionarAtaque = document.getElementById("seleccionar-ataque")
    const sectionReiniciarJuego = document.getElementById("reiniciar")
    const botonMascotaJugador = document.getElementById("boton_mascota")
    const botonReiniciar = document.getElementById("boton-reiniciar")
    
    //seleccionar mascota
    const sectionSeleccionarMascota = document.getElementById("seleccionar-mascota")
    
    
    //seleccion mascota enemigo
    const spanMascotaEnemigo = document.getElementById("mascota-enemigo")
    
    //Combate
    const spanVidasJugador = document.getElementById("vidas-jugador")
    const spanVidasEnemigo = document.getElementById("vidas-enemigo")
    
    //Crear mensaje
    const sectionMensajes = document.getElementById("resultado")
    const ataqueDelJugador = document.getElementById("ataque-del-jugador")
    const ataqueDelEnemigo = document.getElementById("ataque-del-enemigo")
    const contenedorTarjetas = document.getElementById("contenedorTarjetas")
    const contenedorAtaques = document.getElementById("contenedorAtaques")
    
    //Mensaje final
    
    let mokepones = [];
    let botones = [];
    let ataqueJugador = [];
    let ataqueEnemigo = [];
    let indexAtaqueJugador
    let indexAtaqueEnemigo
    let ataquesMokeponEnemigo
    let opcionDeMokepones
    let inputHipodoge
    let inputCapipepo 
    let inputRatigueya
    let inputLangostelvis 
    let inputTucapalma 
    let inputPydos
    let mascotaJugador
    let ataquesMokepon
    let botonFuego
    let botonAgua
    let botonTierra
    let spanMascotaJugador
    let vidasJugador = 3
    let vidasEnemigo = 3
    
    class Mokepon {
        constructor (nombre, imagen, vida) {
            this.nombre = nombre
            this.imagen = imagen
            this.vida = vida
            this.ataques = []
        }
    }
    
    let hipodoge = new Mokepon ("Hipodoge", "./Assets/mokepons_mokepon_hipodoge_attack.webp", 5)
    let capipepo = new Mokepon ("Capipepo", "./Assets/mokepons_mokepon_capipepo_attack.webp", 5)
    let ratigueya = new Mokepon ("Ratigueya", "./Assets/mokepons_mokepon_ratigueya_attack.webp", 5)
    let langostelvis = new Mokepon ("Langostelvis", "./Assets/DALL_E_2022-12-06_18.23.04-removebg-preview.png", 5)
    let tucapalma = new Mokepon ("Tucapalma", "./Assets/DALL_E_2022-12-06_17.39.28-removebg-preview.png", 5)
    let pydos = new Mokepon ("Pydos", "./Assets/DALL_E_2022-12-06_18.22.03-removebg-preview.png", 5)
    
    
    hipodoge.ataques.push( 
        {nombre: "agua", id: "boton_agua"},
        {nombre: "agua", id: "boton_agua"},
        {nombre: "agua", id: "boton_agua"},
        {nombre: "fuego", id: "boton_fuego"},
        {nombre: "tierra", id: "boton_tierra"},
    )
    
    capipepo.ataques.push( 
        {nombre: "tierra", id: "boton_tierra"},
        {nombre: "tierra", id: "boton_tierra"},
        {nombre: "tierra", id: "boton_tierra"},
        {nombre: "agua", id: "boton_agua"},
        {nombre: "fuego", id: "boton_fuego"},
        )
    
    ratigueya.ataques.push( 
        {nombre: "fuego", id: "boton_fuego"},
        {nombre: "fuego", id: "boton_fuego"},
        {nombre: "fuego", id: "boton_fuego"},
        {nombre: "agua", id: "boton_agua"},
        {nombre: "tierra", id: "boton_tierra"},
    )
    
    langostelvis.ataques.push( 
        {nombre: "agua", id: "boton_agua"},
        {nombre: "agua", id: "boton_agua"},
        {nombre: "fuego", id: "boton_fuego"},
        {nombre: "fuego", id: "boton_fuego"},
        {nombre: "tierra", id: "boton_tierra"},
    )
    
    tucapalma.ataques.push( 
        {nombre: "agua", id: "boton_agua"},
        {nombre: "agua", id: "boton_agua"},
        {nombre: "tierra", id: "boton_tierra"},
        {nombre: "tierra", id: "boton_tierra"},
        {nombre: "fuego", id: "boton_fuego"},
    )
    
    pydos.ataques.push( 
        {nombre: "fuego", id: "boton_fuego"},
        {nombre: "fuego", id: "boton_fuego"},
        {nombre: "tierra", id: "boton_tierra"},
        {nombre: "tierra", id: "boton_tierra"},
        {nombre: "agua", id: "boton_agua"},
    )
    
    mokepones.push (hipodoge, capipepo, ratigueya, langostelvis, tucapalma, pydos)
    
    function iniciarJuego() {
        
        sectionSeleccionarAtaque.style.display = "none"
    
        mokepones.forEach((mokepon) => {
            opcionDeMokepones = `
            <input type="radio" id=${mokepon.nombre} name=Mascota />
            <label class ="tarjeta-de-mokepon" for=${mokepon.nombre}>
                <p>${mokepon.nombre}</p>
                <img src=${mokepon.imagen} alt=${mokepon.nombre} >
            </label>
            `
            contenedorTarjetas.innerHTML += opcionDeMokepones
    
            inputHipodoge = document.getElementById('Hipodoge')
            inputCapipepo = document.getElementById("Capipepo")
            inputRatigueya = document.getElementById("Ratigueya")
            inputLangostelvis = document.getElementById("Langostelvis")
            inputTucapalma = document.getElementById("Tucapalma")
            inputPydos = document.getElementById("Pydos")
            spanMascotaJugador = document.getElementById("mascota-jugador")
        })
      
        sectionReiniciarJuego.style.display = "none"
        
        botonMascotaJugador.addEventListener("click", seleccionarMascotaJugador)
        
        botonReiniciar.addEventListener("click", reiniciarJuego)
    }
    
    function seleccionarMascotaJugador() {
        
        sectionSeleccionarMascota.style.display = "none"
        sectionSeleccionarAtaque.style.display = "flex"
    
            if(inputHipodoge.checked){
                spanMascotaJugador.innerHTML = inputHipodoge.id
                mascotaJugador = inputHipodoge.id
        } else if (inputCapipepo.checked) {
            spanMascotaJugador.innerHTML = inputCapipepo.id
            mascotaJugador = inputCapipepo.id
        } else if (inputRatigueya.checked) {
            spanMascotaJugador.innerHTML = inputRatigueya.id
            mascotaJugador = inputRatigueya.id
        } else if (inputLangostelvis.checked) {
            spanMascotaJugador.innerHTML = inputLangostelvis.id
            mascotaJugador = inputLangostelvis.id 
        } else if (inputTucapalma.checked) {
            spanMascotaJugador.innerHTML = inputTucapalma.id
            mascotaJugador = inputTucapalma.id
        } else if (inputPydos.checked) {
            spanMascotaJugador.innerHTML = inputPydos.id
            mascotaJugador = inputPydos.id
        } else {
            alert("No seleccionaste tu mascota")
        }
    
        extraerAtaques(mascotaJugador)
        seleccionarMascotaEnemigo ()
        // Si quiero que una funcion se ejecute despues de otra debo llamarla dentro de la funcion anterior
    }
    
    
    function extraerAtaques(mascotaJugador) {
        let ataques
        for (let i = 0; i < mokepones.length; i++) {
            if (mascotaJugador === mokepones[i].nombre) {
                ataques = mokepones[i].ataques
            }
        }
        mostrarAtaques(ataques)
        
    }
    
    function mostrarAtaques(ataques) {
        ataques.forEach((ataque) => {
            ataquesMokepon = `
            <button id=${ataque.id} class="boton-ataque Bataque">${ataque.nombre} </button>
            `
            contenedorAtaques.innerHTML += ataquesMokepon
        }) 
            botonFuego = document.getElementById("boton_fuego")
            botonAgua = document.getElementById("boton_agua")
            botonTierra = document.getElementById("boton_tierra")
            botones = document.querySelectorAll(".Bataque")
    }
    
    function secuenciaAtaque() {
        botones.forEach ((boton) => {
            boton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
                if (e.target.textContent === "fuego") {
                    ataqueJugador.push("fuego")
                    console.log(ataqueJugador)
                    boton.style.background = "#112f58"
                } else if(e.target.textContent === "agua") {
                    ataqueJugador.push("agua")
                    console.log(ataqueJugador)
                    boton.style.background = "#112f58"
                } else {
                    ataqueJugador.push("tierra")
                    console.log(ataqueJugador)
                    boton.style.background = "#112f58"
                }
                
                ataqueAleatorioEnemigo()
             })
        })
    }
    
    function seleccionarMascotaEnemigo() {
        let enemigoAleatorio = aleatorio(0, mokepones.length -1)
        
        spanMascotaEnemigo.innerHTML = mokepones[enemigoAleatorio].nombre
        ataquesMokeponEnemigo = mokepones[enemigoAleatorio].ataques
        secuenciaAtaque()
    }
    
    
    function ataqueAleatorioEnemigo() {
        let ataqueAleatorio = aleatorio(0, ataquesMokeponEnemigo.length -1)
    
        if (ataqueAleatorio == 0 || ataqueAleatorio == 1) {
            ataqueEnemigo.push("fuego")
        } else if (ataqueAleatorio == 3 || ataqueAleatorio == 4) {
            ataqueEnemigo.push("agua")
        } else {
            ataqueEnemigo.push("tierra")
        }
        iniciarPelea()
        console.log(ataqueEnemigo)
    }
    
    function iniciarPelea() {
        if (ataqueJugador.length === 5) {
            combate()
        }
    }
    
    function indexAmbosOponentes (jugador, enemigo) {
        indexAtaqueJugador = ataqueJugador[jugador]
        indexAtaqueEnemigo = ataqueEnemigo[enemigo]
    
    }
       
    function combate() {
    
            
        for (let index = 0; index < ataqueJugador.length; index++) {
            if (ataqueJugador[index] === ataqueEnemigo[index]) {
                indexAmbosOponentes (jugador, enemigo)
                crearMensaje("Empate")
            }
        }
    
        if (ataqueJugador == ataqueEnemigo) {
            crearMensaje("Empate")
        } else if (ataqueJugador == "fuego" && ataqueEnemigo == "tierra") {
            crearMensaje("GANASTE")
            vidasEnemigo--
            spanVidasEnemigo.innerHTML = vidasEnemigo
        } else if (ataqueJugador == "agua" &&  ataqueEnemigo == "fuego")  {
            crearMensaje("GANASTE")
            vidasEnemigo--
            spanVidasEnemigo.innerHTML = vidasEnemigo
        } else if (ataqueJugador == "tierra" && ataqueEnemigo == "agua") {
            crearMensaje("GANASTE")
            vidasEnemigo--
            spanVidasEnemigo.innerHTML = vidasEnemigo
        } else {
            crearMensaje("PERDISTE")
            vidasJugador--
            spanVidasJugador.innerHTML = vidasJugador
        }
    
        revisarVidas()
    }
    
    function revisarVidas() {
        if (vidasEnemigo == 0) {
            mensajeFinal("FELICITACIONES GANASTE!!!")
        } else if (vidasJugador == 0)  {
            mensajeFinal("LO SIENTO; PERDISTE. VUELVE A JUGAR")
        } 
    }
    
    function crearMensaje(resultado) {
        
        let nuevoAtaqueJugador = document.createElement("p")
        let nuevoAtaqueEnemigo = document.createElement("p")
        
        sectionMensajes.innerHTML = resultado
        nuevoAtaqueJugador.innerHTML =  indexAtaqueJugador
        nuevoAtaqueEnemigo.innerHTML = indexAtaqueEnemigo
    
        ataqueDelJugador.appendChild(nuevoAtaqueJugador)
        ataqueDelEnemigo.appendChild(nuevoAtaqueEnemigo)
    }
    
    function mensajeFinal(resultadoFinal) {
        sectionMensajes.innerHTML = resultadoFinal
        
        botonFuego.disabled = true
        botonAgua.disabled = true
        botonTierra.disabled = true
        
        sectionReiniciarJuego.style.display = "block"
    }
    
    function reiniciarJuego ()   {
        location.reload()
    }
    
    function aleatorio(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
    }
    
    window.addEventListener("load", iniciarJuego)
```

Comment: Puedes agregar el HTML?, si no es mucha molestia.

Comment: Pueden ser muchos factores que ocasionen ese comportamiento, puede ser un error en la forma en la que se ejecutan los eventos de los ataques o que el botonTierra esté sobrescribiendo los eventos de los demás botones, en todo caso como comentan arriba es necesario que nos compartas el resto de código para revisar.